# Is Full Text Search just as effecient when indexing integers separated by spaces in the same column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, indexing

I.E. Does full text search work just as well/better searching through *only* integers separated by spaces and indexed using the "full text index"?

Thanks!

Comment: @antlersoft -- as searching text, which I assume utilizes the language dictionary specified upon creation of the catalog/index.

Comment: I would think it would be more efficient using a full "integer" index, but still needs to be created under a varchar/nvarchar/image type due to needing to space the strings/ints within the catalog

Comment: Since the integers are separated by spaces I am assuming this is stored in a varchar/nvarchar/text column. In that case, full-text will index the strings just fine but you may run into stop list issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Yes. Tried this with over a million rows.